# Ending an "infinite" stream when certain conditions are met

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to pull data from a REST-style web-service which delivers content in pages.

The only way I can know that I've reached the end is when I ask for a page and there are no results. I'd like to terminate the stream at that time.

I've written the following Java code. The first function pulls a single page from the web-service and returns it as a stream. The second function flatmaps the streams together into a single stream.

```
public Stream<ApplicationResponse> getApplications(String token, RestTemplate rt, Integer page, Integer pageSize) {
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("parameters", getHeaders(token));
    String url = String.format("%s?PageIndex=%s&PageSize=%s", endpoint, page, pageSize);
    ResponseEntity<ApplicationCollection> ar = rt.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, ApplicationCollection.class);
    ApplicationResponse[] res = Objects.requireNonNull(ar.getBody()).getData();

    // Do something here when res is empty, so that the stream ends

    return Arrays.stream(res);
}

public Stream<ApplicationResponse> getApplications(String token, RestTemplate rt) {
    // This function does the right thing, exept when we run out of data!
    return IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1).mapToObj(i -> getApplications(token, rt, i, 500)).flatMap(Function.identity());
}
```

The problem is, how do I allow this to end?

If I were writing this in Python I'd raise a StopIteration exception at the point where I know there's nothing left to put onto the stream. Is there something similar I can do?

The best thing I could think of was use a null, or raise an exception to signify the end of data and then wrap up the stream into an Iterator that knows to stop when that signal is received. But is there anything more idiomatic that I can do?

Comment: [Not before Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-)…

Comment: What if the inner function raises an exception, is there a way I can handle that normally and just allow the stream to end?

Comment: Not when you want to get a result from the operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After comments from Holger, I gave it a shot and tried `Spliterator` instead of `Iterator`. It is indeed simpler, as `next` and `hasNext` are... kinda combined into `tryAdvance`? It is even short enough to just inline it into a util method, imo.

```
public static Stream<ApplicationResponse> getApplications(String token, RestTemplate rt)
{
    return StreamSupport.stream(new AbstractSpliterator<ApplicationResponse[]>(Long.MAX_VALUE,
                                                                               Spliterator.ORDERED
                                                                                               | Spliterator.IMMUTABLE)
    {
        private int page = 1;

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super ApplicationResponse[]> action)
        {
            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("parameters", getHeaders(token));
            String url = String.format("%s?PageIndex=%s&PageSize=%s", endpoint, page, 500);
            ResponseEntity<ApplicationCollection> ar = rt.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity,
                                                                   ApplicationCollection.class);
            ApplicationResponse[] res = Objects.requireNonNull(ar.getBody()).getData();

            if (res.length == 0)
                return false;

            page++;
            action.accept(res);
            return true;
        }
    }, false).flatMap(Arrays::stream);
}
```

---

You could implement an Iterator and create a Stream of it:

```
public class ResponseIterator
    implements Iterator<Stream<ApplicationResponse>>
{
    private int                   page = 1;
    private String                token;
    private RestTemplate          rt;

    private ApplicationResponse[] next;

    private ResponseIterator(String token, RestTemplate rt)
    {
        this.token = token;
        this.rt = rt;
    }

    public static Stream<ApplicationResponse> getApplications(String token, RestTemplate rt)
    {
        Iterable<Stream<ApplicationResponse>> iterable = () -> new ResponseIterator(token, rt);
        return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false).flatMap(Function.identity());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        if (next == null)
        {
            next = getNext();
        }
        return next.length != 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Stream<ApplicationResponse> next()
    {
        if (next == null)
        {
            next = getNext();
        }
        Stream<ApplicationResponse> nextStream = Arrays.stream(next);
        next = getNext();
        return nextStream;
    }

    private ApplicationResponse[] getNext()
    {
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("parameters", getHeaders(token));
        String url = String.format("%s?PageIndex=%s&PageSize=%s", endpoint, page, 500);
        ResponseEntity<ApplicationCollection> ar = rt.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity,
                                                               ApplicationCollection.class);
        ApplicationResponse[] res = Objects.requireNonNull(ar.getBody()).getData();
        page++;
        return res;
    }
}
```

It will check whether the next response is empty in `hasNext()`, stopping the stream. Otherwise, it will stream and flatMap that response. I have hardwired `pageSize`, but you can easily make that a third input for the factory method `ResponseIterator.getApplications()`.

Comment: Try to do the same using `Spliterator` instead of `Iterator`. You’ll see that it is actually simpler.

Comment: @Holger is this simplicity coming from the fact that it's a single method "to do", `tryAdvance`? feels good to be back btw :)

Comment: @Eugene a single method with a straight-forward logic matching the task. In contrast, the two `Iterator` methods need additional checks whether there is already a queried value. Also, the `Iterator` must get wrapped into a `Spliterator` when creating the `Stream`. This answer’s solution uses an additional detour via creating an `Iterable` to call `spliterator()` which will end up at `Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize` which you could also invoke directly, but it’s not needed when implementing a `Spliterator` in the first place.

Comment: @Holger When I tried implemeting Spliterator directly at first, it was quite a bit of bulk around the `tryAdvance`. I found the abstract implementation an managed to shorten it. Remembered to override `forEachRemaining` but found that it didn't really offer any benefit in this case. Do the chosen parameters(`characteristics`, `estimatedSize`) make sense. Did I understand the implementation of `trySplit` correctly in that `Long.MAX_VALUE` makes sure it does not parallelize?

Comment: I just noticed the comment, however better answer late than never. Bits must be combined with binary OR, i.e. `Spliterator.ORDERED|Spliterator.IMMUTABLE`. Providing no `SIZED` and `Long.MAX_VALUE` as estimate has the meaning of “unknown size”, but this doesn’t imply that there was no splitting support. The inherited implementation will call your `tryAdvance`, buffering the elements into an array and return an array based spliterator. There is nothing wrong with that, your code still is called by one thread only. It just means, you only get a benefit from parallel if you chain heavy operations.