# Create a Stream from an object's method

Tags: java-8, java-stream

what is a best way of initializating a Stream with and object's method?

```
Foo foo1 = new Foo();
Foo foo2 = foo1.getNext();
Foo foo3 = foo2.getNext();
```

And I want a Stream of foo, foo1, foo2,... through the getNext() method.

I tried

```
Stream.iterate
Stream.generate
```

but these methods returns infinite streams.

Comment: .limit(.......)

Comment: Size is unknown and all Foos cannot be retrieved eagerly, as it is very resource heavy method.

Comment: can you use `Stream.of()`

Comment: How do you know when to stop? Note that streams are not eager, they will only produce elements as they are consumed. You might be interested in [Ending an “infinite” stream when certain conditions are met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49978246/ending-an-infinite-stream-when-certain-conditions-are-met).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `Stream.iterate(foo1, Foo::getNext)`. You didn’t tell under which condition it should stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not specified in the question, but I believe you want to stop iterating when `getNext()` returns `null` (it seems to make the most sense).

If so, there are at least three ways:

1. If on JDK 9+, do what [Aominè](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5862071/aomin%C3%A8) suggested:

   ```
   Stream.iterate(foo1, Objects::nonNull, Foo::getNext)
   ```
2. If on JDK 8, and you don't mind introducing an extra dependency, use [jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) and its [iterateWhilePresent](https://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/0.9.14/org/jooq/lambda/Seq.html#iterateWhilePresent-T-java.util.function.Function-) method:

   ```
   Seq.iterateWhilePresent(foo1, foo -> Optional.ofNullable(foo.getNext))
   ```
3. If on JDK 8 and you *don't* want to introduce an extra dependency, write a method utilizing a custom `Spliterator`, for example (note that this is not the most efficient implementation as it calls `generator` eagerly):

   ```
   public static <T> Stream<T> iterateUntilNull(T seed, UnaryOperator<T> generator) {
       Spliterator<T> spliterator = new Spliterator<T>() {
           private T next = seed;

           @Override
           public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
               if (next == null) {
                   return false;
               }
               action.accept(next);
               next = generator.apply(next);
               return true;
           }

           @Override
           public Spliterator<T> trySplit() {
               return null;
           }

           @Override
           public long estimateSize() {
               return Long.MAX_VALUE;
           }

           @Override
           public int characteristics() {
               return Spliterator.NONNULL;
           }
       };
       return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, false);
   }
   ```

   and then call:

   ```
   iterateUntilNull(foo1, Foo::getNext)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First idea that may come to mind would be to truncate the stream with `limit`:

```
Stream.iterate(foo1, Foo::getNext)
      .limit(size)....
```

but obviously, this is not useful if the size is unknown.

if the size is unknown then surely there must be some type of condition to say "stop and no more".

[JDK-9 offers these overloads:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-)

```
Stream.iterate(foo1, Foo::getNext)
      .takeWhile(f -> someCondition)
      ....  // further intermediate or a terminal operation
```

or:

```
Stream.iterate(foo1, f -> someCondition, Foo::getNext)
      .... // further intermediate or a terminal operation
```

if you cannot use JDK-9 then your only other option is to create your own helper method to perform the logic you're after.